# How to count the amount of objects by id in a list using parse

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, back4app

I've done the count with a single object using promises but when I tried to do it with a list of objects it displayed the counted object with the same number of objects in the list.

I already display the vehicles but I need to display their routes.

Here's the code for getting the list of vehicles

```
const Car = Parse.Object.extend('Vehicle');
const query = new Parse.Query(Car);

//car search
app.get('/car-search', async function (req, res) {

    const VehicleInfo = [];
    query.notEqualTo("Route", null);
    query.notEqualTo("PassengerAmount", null);

    try {
        const result = await query.find();

        result.forEach(vehicle => {

            VehicleInfo.push({
                VehicleID: vehicle.id,
                VehicleImage: vehicle.get("Image")._url,
                VehicleName: vehicle.get('Name'),
                Description: vehicle.get('Description'),
                Price: vehicle.get('Price'),
                Rating: vehicle.get('Rating'),
                Route: vehicle.get('Route'),
                PassengerAmount: vehicle.get('PassengerAmount')
            });
        });
        res.render('car-search', {
            title: 'Vehiculos',
            VehicleData: VehicleInfo
        });
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }

});
```

Here's the code to do the count, I use this in another page to display only a single vehicle.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let FoundVehicles = result[i];
        let CountRoute = query.count(FoundVehicles.get('Route'));
        let Count = CountRoute.then(function(data){

            return data;
        })

        let RouteAmount = (await Count).valueOf(FoundVehicles.get('Route'))

          VehicleInfo.push({
            VehicleName: FoundVehicles.get('Name'),
            Description: FoundVehicles.get('Description'),
            Price: FoundVehicles.get('Price'),
            Rating: FoundVehicles.get('Rating'),
            Route: RouteAmount,
            PassengerAmount: FoundVehicles.get('PassengerAmount')
        });
}
```

This is what the console displays in the list if I use the count there
[list of counted routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKgeB.png)

This is an example of what I'm trying to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UZHC.png)
The "Reseñas" part (reviews) one of the cars should have 2, the other 3 and so on

Comment: Can you please share how your are initializing the `query` var in both examples? Can you also share your schema?

Comment: I've added how I declare and initialize the query, but I'm not using schemas here, I'm storing everything in back4app

Comment: Got it, but can you share how is the schema for your class Car? I mean, which fields and types you have there. At least the important ones for this issue.

Comment: The importante one is query.count(FoundVehicles.get('Route')), the data type is string and I need to count each route of each vehicle and display them

Comment: I didn't get it. Are you saying that the `Route` field in the `Vehicle` class is a `String`? What exactly do you need to retrieve? Can you please provide an example? It would be helpful if you could give an example of input and output you expect to have with your query.

Comment: I'm sorry if I confuse you, what i'm trying to retrieve is the number of routes that each vehicle has, as you can see in the picture I have a total on 9 vehicles, it outputs the number 9, 9 times, instead of outputing 1,3,4, etc etc. It doesn't matter if the Route field is a String, a Number, etc.

Comment: It actually matters and I still can not understand what you need to achieve. It would be really helpful if you could provide an example of input and output.

Comment: I uploaded an image of how it should look like

Comment: I understood what you need to achieve. But I'd still need to understand how your data is structured inside Parse. What type is the field Route?

Comment: It's a string, the user, when adding a new vehicle, can add a new route aside from the one that's already there, write the name of the new route and display the amount of routes of that vehicle in the list.

Comment: It is a string with the list of routes separate by comma? Can you provide one example of this string?

Comment: Yes, it's a list of routes separated by comma. Example: Route:["test street","test avenue","test street 2"]

Comment: So Route is not a String. It is an Array. I will post a possible solution. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let FoundVehicles = result[i];
        let RouteAmount = FoundVehicles.get('Route').length;

          VehicleInfo.push({
            VehicleName: FoundVehicles.get('Name'),
            Description: FoundVehicles.get('Description'),
            Price: FoundVehicles.get('Price'),
            Rating: FoundVehicles.get('Rating'),
            Route: RouteAmount,
            PassengerAmount: FoundVehicles.get('PassengerAmount')
        });
}
```